# Breakpoint not hitting get statement

Tags: c#, debugging, async-await, user-controls, httpclient

I am implementing a windows form application and I have a user control list which is loaded on form load. Here is my user control code.

```cs
public partial class Issuepost : UserControl
{
    public Issuepost()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        customizedesign();
    }

    static Model.Funds FundsDetails;
    public int IssueId { get; set; }
    public string issueStatement { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
    public string IssueImage { get; set; }
    public string UserImage { get; set; }
    public int userrating { get; set; }

    private void IssueImage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] arr = Convert.FromBase64String(IssueImage);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arr))
        {
            issue_image.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        byte[] arr2 = Convert.FromBase64String(UserImage);
        using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(arr2))
        {
            userImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms1);
        }
        label_time.Text = IssueDate.ToString();
        label_username.Text = UserName;
        //  labeltest.Text = IssueId.ToString();
        bunifuRating1.Value = userrating / 2;

        Worker_DoWork();
    }
     
    private async void Worker_DoWork()
    {
        FundsDetails = await Model.Funds.GetFundById(IssueId);
    }
```

and here is the GetFundById(IssueId) method:

```
public static async Task<Funds> GetFundById(int id)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string uri = Issues.baseuri + "/api/volunteer/getfundbyid/?id=" + id;
    string response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    var contents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Funds>(response);
    return contents;
}
```

Funds data was not being shown in UI, so when I debugged I saw that when the program hit the GetFundById() Method, it started looping in the first three lines of this method and after several loops the UI opened with no data.

It is restarting the method (with different Issue Id) after this line:

```cs
string response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

What is this behaviour and how can I solve this?. I have made sure that this Uri is actually returning a value by using postman.

Comment: In the constructor you need to load the variable IssueImage.

Comment: Change async void to async task

Answer (score 0):

If the remote destination address supports the post method, you must post the id in the Json format and then return your request. Follow the code below to do this.

```
public static async Task<Funds> GetFundById(int id)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string uri = Issues.baseuri + "/api/volunteer/getfundbyid";

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
    string response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var contents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Funds>(response);
    return contents;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as well. Please highlight how does your solution proposal might solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @PeterCsala I changed the code a bit and added explanations.